# Is there an R package to calculate differential entropy

Tags: continuous-data, entropy

I am trying to calculate differential entropy over my data. This is how a subset of my data set looks like :

```
test.Kidney.meth    0.0666666   0.129032    0.0333333   0   0   0
test.Liver.meth 0.25    0.0625  0.1875  0   0   0
test.brain.meth 0.0192308   0   0.0196079   0.0526316   0.1 0
test.lung.meth  0.15625 0.0937498   0.125   0   0.25    0.333333
test.panc.meth  0   0   0   0.0454546   0.2 0.333333
test.pericard.meth  0.101449    0.0735294   0.102941    0.151515    0.05    0.153846
test.skin.meth  0.030303    0.030303    0.0588235   0.0833333   0.181818    0
test.uterus.meth    0.0441177   0.0294117   0.0434783   0.0416666   0.0526316   0.125
```

I am trying to compute entropy for every column and then will just average it out over all the columns. While going through different R packages I found that most of them discretize the continuous data and then compute the entropy. Since my data is small (in terms of number of rows or length of each column vector) I doubt that I would get reliable results. Thus I was wondering if there is any R package available which calculates differential entropy. Or Entropy over Continuous data.

Comment: What is the larger aim of your study? Could some other method also achieve that aim?

Comment: Here is an implementation for Java: https://code.google.com/p/information-dynamics-toolkit/wiki/ImplementedMeasures maybe you can try calling Java code from R.

Comment: Using `R` is no assurance of reliable results.  *Understanding* what the code does and making sure it is appropriate for your data and your objectives are what you need: that's why answering the questions posed by @rnso is important.

Answer (score 2):

There is this package EntropyMCMC for differential entropy which still seems to be in progress

For entropy over continuous data use

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/np/vignettes/entropy_np.pdf

or

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/entropy.pdf      (not sure if this does the job)